# What IAM Policies control Firebase Function Configs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iam

I would like to manage which of my developers has access to firebase configs, or at the very least not allow them to edit them:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

I can't find documentation on which policy controls it (I found `firebase remote config` but it's something different).

What is the IAM policy for controlling whether someone can access the firebase config? Or the ability to edit them?

Also, is there a UI where I can see where the configs are in GCP / Firebase console? I only see commandline options `firebase functions:config:get`.

Comment: I think Firebase Functions is based on Could Functions, so maybe you should look for roles based on Could Functions.

Comment: @Gray_Rhino I thought about that, but the firebase configs seem to be specific to firebase :/ I could be wrong, but that's what I found. I did look around for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cloud Functions for Firebase `functions.config()` is powered by Cloud Runtime Configurator under the covers. The permissions that you'll need are [listed in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/runtime-configurator/access-control). Read/write access to both `configs` and `variables` is necessary to manage `functions.config()`.

Unfortunately there are no curated roles available for Runtime Conifgurator, but the permissions are included in the Firebase Develop Admin role.

Comment: Awesome, it looks like that link is what I needed, I can specify only read access to my devs and not add write access. Thank you :)